# Auto increment primary key with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I have an association like this - order having many sub orders which in turn has many line items. I am trying to update the order - some with existing line item ids and create some new ones. My request is as follows.

```
order: {
  id: order.id,
  sub_orders_attributes: {
    "0": {
      id: 1,
      line_items_attributes: [
        {
          id: 1,
          requested: 10
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          requested: 10
        }
      ]
    },
    "1": {
      line_items_attributes: [
        {
          requested: 10
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now with this, I get this error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value 
violates unique constraint "sub_orders_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

as I haven't supplied ids for the new items. Also this issue does not appear in dev/production environments. Only with rspec. Any suggestions on how I can solve this? Thanks.

Comment: did you add and setup the [database cleaner gem](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) ?

Comment: How is your payload processed? Also, could you share a bit more about your test setup?